# How do you catch events for elements inside dynamic datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a dynamic datatable where data are loaded by Ajax.
My HTML is:

```
<table id="dynamic_table"></table>
```

and the JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dynamic_table').DataTable( {
            "ajax": '/ajax_handler',
            ...
$('td').on('click', function(e){
    alert("I'm td")
});
$('body').on('click', function(e){
    alert("I'm body")
});
```

Well 'body' is caught but 'td' is not. Of course the browser shows rows with their tr/td tags but it seems like that (dynamic) loaded data aren't still seen by the JS.

How I can catch clicks to my dynamic td? How I can bind them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running into is your DataTable create td elements after you bind those click events. There are 2 alternatives, re bind all event listenes to TD after table renders, or using event bubbling to capturate click event to parent component.
There is a jQuery [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) argument you can pass to tell the table listen for click events.

```js
$('table').on('click', 'td', function(e){
    alert("I'm td")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign class to td and bind event handler to this class.

$.on('event.js-name', function(){});